# Conditionally Adding Multiple Child XElements

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am able to conditionally add a single child xelement using the below code however when I try to add multiple xelements I get syntax warnings. How can I add multiple?

OK

```
 new XElement("AllNumbers",
              bonusNumbers.Any() ? 
              from n in bonusNumbers select 
              new XElement("BonusNumbers", bonusNumbers.ToArray())
              :null),
```

Not OK

```
 new XElement("AllNumbers",
              numbers.Any() ? 
              from n in numbers select 
              new XElement("Numbers", numbers.ToArray())
              :null;

              bonusNumbers.Any() ? 
              from n in bonusNumbers select 
              new XElement("BonusNumbers", bonusNumbers.ToArray())
              :null),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new XElement("AllNumbers",
  numbers.Any() ?
  from n in numbers
  select new XElement("Numbers", numbers.ToArray())
  : null, // should be , instead of ;

  bonusNumbers.Any() ?
  from n in bonusNumbers
  select new XElement("BonusNumbers", bonusNumbers.ToArray())
  : null);
```

Btw its not clear why you are adding all numbers for each number in collection. Possibly you should use not use queries here:

```
new XElement("AllNumbers",
    numbers.Any() ? new XElement("Numbers", numbers) : null,
    bonusNumbers.Any() ? new XElement("BonusNumbers", bonusNumbers) : null);
```

Or if you want to put each number in own element:

```
new XElement("AllNumbers",
    numbers.Any() ? 
         new XElement("Numbers", 
             numbers.Select(n => new XElement("Number", n))) : null,
    bonusNumbers.Any() ? 
         new XElement("BonusNumbers", 
             bonusNumbers.Select(n => new XElement("Number", n))) : null);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice that...I have been concentrating on getting the multiple children added that I was not paying attention :)